# AWS SDK Error: A JNI error has occurred, ... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to do the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.01.html) using the SDK specified [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html).

Specifically, I am trying to execute the following Amazon Web Services DynamoDB sample code with Maven:

https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/DynamoDBTutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/basicapp/MoviesCreateTable.java

Like so...

```
c4b301bb8ad9:myapp StackOverflowUser$ pwd
/Users/StackOverflowUser/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/myapp

c4b301bb8ad9:myapp StackOverflowUser$ ./../mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myapp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/StackOverflowUser/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/myapp/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myapp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/StackOverflowUser/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/myapp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/StackOverflowUser/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/myapp/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.example.basicapp.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ myapp ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.557 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-20T13:37:59-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I try to run it I get this error...

```
c4b301bb8ad9:myapp StackOverflowUser$ java -cp target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.example.basicapp.MoviesCreateTable
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
c4b301bb8ad9:myapp StackOverflowUser$
```

The Java version I am running is...

```
StackOverflowUser$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

And I am running [this jar file](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/DynamoDBTutorial/blob/master/target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) with this Mac version...

[image: About this Mac]

I tried adding to pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.example.basicapp.MoviesCreateTable</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

And then:

```
$ ./../mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

But when I run it I get:

```
$ java -cp target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.example.basicapp.MoviesCreateTable
Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.basicapp.MoviesCreateTable
```

Comment: Do you use the same `pom.xml` as the one in https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/DynamoDBTutorial/blob/master/pom.xml ? Do you see `aws-java-sdk` jar file in your local `.m2` repository ?

Comment: I can't seem to find a directory named .m2 in my project or in the unzipped jar file.

Comment: c4b301bb8ad9:myapp StackOverflowUser$ pwd
    /Users/StackOverflowUser/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/myapp
    c4b301bb8ad9:myapp StackOverflowUser$ find ./ -name ".m2"
    c4b301bb8ad9:myapp StackOverflowUser$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classloader can't load a class you are importing (`com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table`.

You can prove this by running `unzip -l myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

It is missing because your final jar artifact is packed without its dependency (`aws-java-sdk`).

Please check if this dependency is reachable from your remote repository (in this case, maven central) and is downloaded to your local `.m2` repository.

You can include it explicitly by using [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>org.example.basicapp.MoviesCreateTable</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And then package it by running `mvn clean compile assembly:single`.

A new jar will be created - `myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` (along side your original jar),and now you don't have to specifiy the main class (you already did in the plugin configuration and it set it up to you on the jar manifest), just run `java -jar target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: I can't seem to find a directory named .m2 in my project or in the unzipped jar file. The command  find ./ -name ".m2"  yields no results.

Comment: I followed your instructions and now I'm getting: $ java -cp target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.example.basicapp.MoviesCreateTable
Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.basicapp.MoviesCreateTable

Comment: `.m2` is an hidden directory on your home root directory - `~/.m2`

Comment: The new jar with dependencies will be named differently, and now you don't have to specifiy the main class (you already did in the plugin configuration and it set it up to you on the jar manifest), just run `java -jar target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: When I do  find ./ -name "aws-java-sdk"  from the ~/.m2 directory I get .//com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk , so it's currently there. When I run  java -jar target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar  it works. Thanks.